# Bootstrap: How can I set the items of my nav bar horizontally?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

can anybody help me please...
I'm trying to set the menu items of my nav horizontally.

Here's my header:

```
<meta charset=amp;quot;utf-8amp;quot;>
<meta http-equiv=amp;quot;X-UA-Compatibleamp;quot; content=amp;quot;IE=edgeamp;quot;>
<meta name=amp;quot;viewportamp;quot; content=amp;quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1amp;quot;>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And this is my menu view:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">

   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Inicio <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Opcion 1</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Opcion 2</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Opcion 3</a></li>

          </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Pagina 2</a></li>

       <li><a href="#">Pagina 3</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>     
   </div>
</nav>
```

I'm getting the menu items vertically, but I don't want that... just horizontally.
Please help me

Comment: is this the desired result?
http://www.bootply.com/0BoQkgA9ak
the first level items are horizontal and second level is a dropdown (vertical)

Comment: That's the result that I was hoping. But I copied and pasted your code in my project and I still having items bellow the other items. I don't know what I'm doing wrong :/

Comment: i used your code, because i thought that it seems fine :)
so my best guess would be to reverse the including of css and js files
first include the css in your header and then include the js files just before closing the body tag.

Comment: Heey It's working fine now! Thanks a lot for your help @flynorc :)

Comment: glad i could help. not sure what the policy is, if i should format it as an answer so people coming to this question at later point can see it, or not?
anyone with more experience please advise if you are reading this :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Opcion 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Opcion 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Opcion 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pagina 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pagina 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Hi @argoden! That not solve my problem because I need the dropdown-menu in that item 'cause I have sub-items to display in that option.

Comment: i updated the post, this is what i get when this coded gets rendered.
What do you mean get the menu items horizontally?

this is original view: http://spireon.d.pr/F5qk